# How to get max Version number from Version table in Database?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, version

I am managing versions in my Application. I have made table name "Version". There are three separate column for "Major", "Minor" and "Bug". My version number are stored in table like this:

---

### Id |  Major |  Minor |  Bug | No

### 1  |    1   |    0   |   0  | 1.0.0

### 2  |    1   |    1   |   3  | 1.1.3

### 3  |    2   |    0   |   4  | 2.0.4

### 4  |    3   |    0   |   1  | 3.0.1

Here my max version should be 3.0.1 as it is highest in current scenario. I am unable to get this max record. My project is in .Net Core 3.0 and i am using entity framework core.

What i tried so far !
I was concatenating each version number like 1.0.0, 1.1.3 and so on, then i was getting list order by descending and was getting first or default. It was working good but for only single digits. When i try it on double digits it was not working.

var model =await DbSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.No).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just order on multiple columns?

```
var model = await DbSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Major).ThenByDescending(x => x.Minor).ThenByDescending(x => x.Bug).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```